# Разворачивающаяся таблица

Tags: objective-c, ios

Здравствуйте, нужна информация о том, как сделать разворачивающуюся таблицу, чтобы при нажатии на хедер секции показывалось его содержимое, при повторном нажатии содержимое скрывалось. Кто-нибудь уже задавался подобным вопросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На [гитхабе](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=expandable&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories) довольно много различных реализаций.

Я успешно использовал [UIExpandableTableView](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView) в двух проектах.